# Spacing between tcolorboxes

Tags: spacing, tcolorbox, labels, vertical-spacing, horizontal-spacing

I would like to make labels for printing but I would like to have bigger spacing (vertical and horizontal) between the labels. I'm working with tcolorboxes and here's my code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin=2cm,vmargin=1.9cm}


\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{raster}

\newtcolorbox{cadreint}
{
  arc is angular,
  colback=white,
  arc=4.5pt,
  boxrule=1pt
}

\newcommand{\etiquette}[1]{\begin{cadreint}\vspace{#1}\end{cadreint}}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=2,raster equal height,
colframe=black,colback=white, arc is angular, arc=8pt, left=1.1pt,right=1.1pt,top=1.1pt,bottom=1.1pt, boxrule=2.4pt,]
\tcbitem[]
\etiquette{3.9cm}
\tcbitem[]
\etiquette{3.9cm}
\tcbitem[]
\etiquette{3.9cm}
\tcbitem[]
\etiquette{3.9cm}
\tcbitem[]
\etiquette{3.9cm}
\tcbitem[]
\etiquette{3.9cm}
\tcbitem[]
\etiquette{3.9cm}
\tcbitem[]
\etiquette{3.9cm}
\tcbitem[]
\etiquette{3.9cm}
\tcbitem[]
\etiquette{3.9cm}

\end{tcbitemize}

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=3,raster equal height,
colframe=black,colback=white, arc is angular, arc=8pt, left=1.1pt,right=1.1pt,top=1.1pt,bottom=1.1pt, width=(\linewidth-9)/3, boxrule=2.4pt,]
\tcbitem[]
\etiquette{2.9cm}
\tcbitem[]
\etiquette{2.9cm}
\tcbitem[]
\etiquette{2.9cm}
\tcbitem[]
\etiquette{2.9cm}
\tcbitem[]
\etiquette{2.9cm}
\tcbitem[]
\etiquette{2.9cm}
\tcbitem[]
\etiquette{2.9cm}
\tcbitem[]
\etiquette{2.9cm}
\tcbitem[]
\etiquette{2.9cm}
\tcbitem[]
\etiquette{2.9cm}
\tcbitem[]
\etiquette{2.9cm}
\tcbitem[]
\etiquette{2.9cm}
\tcbitem[]
\etiquette{2.9cm}
\tcbitem[]
\etiquette{2.9cm}
\tcbitem[]
\etiquette{2.9cm}
\tcbitem[]
\etiquette{2.9cm}
\tcbitem[]
\etiquette{2.9cm}
\tcbitem[]
\etiquette{2.9cm}
\end{tcbitemize}
\end{document}
```

Here in light red is where I want it to be bigger (but it's fine if the spacing is also bigger on the other sides of the labels).
[image]

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: `raster column skip` and `raster row skip`

Comment: Thank you that's perfectly want I wanted !